# Ignore empty list in hibernate native query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a query

```
 String query = "Select * 
                   from brand brd 
                   join product prd on brd.prd_id = prd.id
                   join price prc on prc.id = prd.prc_id";

 if(!bo.brd.isEmpty() || !bo.prd.isEmpty())
 query.append(" where " );
 if(!bo.brd.isEmpty()) && !bo.prd.isEmpty())
 query.append(brd.id in (:brdId) and prd.id in (:prdId));
 else if(!bo.brd.isEmpty())
 query.append(brd.id in (:brdId)) ;
 else if(!bo.prd.isEmpty())
 query.append( prd.id in (:prdId));

 query.createNativeQuery(query)
 .setParameterList("brdId", brdLst)
 .setParameterList("prdId", prdLst)
 .getResultList();
```

All the parameters are optional. I am using hibernate native query and setting all the parameters using setParameterlist. When the list is empty or if it is not able the find the parameter I am getting brdId not found or prdId not found . How Can I dynamically change the query parameters?

Comment: some really messed up if-else conditions. What I understood from the question you want to add brandList and productList as parameter based on their availability. Right?

Comment: At first it won't compile. Variable `query` declared as String doesn't have hibernate methods...
Try debugging your code because there are few mistakes in both `if` statements, later when trying to `setParameterList` don't call next method immedietely, use same `if-else` conditions to set propper params, e.g. having `q.creaateNativeQuery` in next if-else, call required `q.setParameterList`

Comment: In addition first `if` should probably be ` if(!bo.brd.isEmpty() || !bo.prd.isEmpty())` and second `if(!bo.brd.isEmpty()) && !bo.prd.isEmpty())` - second condition in both were missing the `!`

Answer (score 0):

the whole thing should be like below

```
String query = "Select * 
               from brand brd 
               join product prd on brd.prd_id = prd.id
               join price prc on prc.id = prd.prc_id";
if(!bo.brd.isEmpty() || !bo.prd.isEmpty())
  query.append(" where " );
if(!bo.brd.isEmpty()) && !bo.prd.isEmpty())
  query.append(brd.id in (:brdId) and prd.id in (:prdId));
else if(!bo.brd.isEmpty())
  query.append(brd.id in (:brdId)) ;
else if(!bo.prd.isEmpty())
   query.append( prd.id in (:prdId));

if(!bo.brd.isEmpty()) && !bo.prd.isEmpty())
  query.createNativeQuery(query).setParameterList("brdId",brdLst).setParameterList("prdId", prdLst);
else if(!bo.brd.isEmpty())
  query.createNativeQuery(query).setParameterList("brdId", brdLst)
else if(!bo.prd.isEmpty())
  query.createNativeQuery(query).setParameterList("prdId", prdLst)
```

And yes 'query' is String it wont have hibernate methods.

Comment: Thanks @Mohd since we only have 2 parameters its easy to put in for loop, but when I start adding the parameters, then no of combination gonna be to much like N! times. I am expecting something dynamically setting the parameters

Comment: @Vivek you are dynamically modifying the query and expecting that hibernate automatically identify what are the conditions available in where clause and then set the parameters accordingly. This idea is theoretically not correct. Maybe, in this case, you can go with criteria queries, where you just need to add a particular restriction based on the available list of parameters.